# Greedy negative lookbehind (in Swift)

Tags: swift, regex

I'm in need of a regular expression that acts like the following:

**matches** (any part of `foo()` in the following statement):

- `foo()`
- `arg: foo()`
- `foo()`
- `(arg: foo()) {}`

**does not match**:

- `@foo()`

I currently have the following, but it has some problems:

```regex
^\s*?(?<!@)((\w+?)\()
```

- `^\s*?` includes any whitespace at the beginning of the line, which means `arg: foo()` doesn't match the `foo()` bit. I had to include this to get the `@` lookbehind working correctly;
- `(?<!@)` is a lookbehind to discard the match if a `@` before the `thing()` is matched;
- `(\w+?)\(` matches the part of `thething(` correctly, only if there's no `@` before it.

If there's no `^\s*?` in the regex, it would be behaving partly correct, but this shouldn't happen. It should rather discard the match entirely (not just for one character):

[image: wrongly matched regex]

It has to discard the match entirely if any `@` is before it, although it must match this correctly: `@Mode foo()` (the `foo()` bit, disregarding the `@Mode` before it).

If there are any tips to help me out, that would be awesome!

Comment: Perhaps add a word boundary `(?<!@)\b\w+\(\)` https://regex101.com/r/D1VXVA/1

Comment: Or `\b(?<!@)\w+(?=\()`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RuFhgP/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<![\w@])\w+\(\)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZYMt1k/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w@]                    any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```